# Set non-primitive types when returning from thread

Tags: java, multithreading

My question is: why does setting a non-primitive type work when returning threads ?

The following works:

```
final int[] newTask = new int[1];
    try{
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                newTask[0] = someMethod();
                return;
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        if(thread.isAlive()){
            thread.interrupt();
            newTask[0] = null;
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException ie){
        log.error("Timeout", ie);
    }
```

The following doesn't:

```
final int newTask;
    try{
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                newTask = someMethod();
                return;
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        if(thread.isAlive()){
            thread.interrupt();
            newTask = null;
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException ie){
        log.error("Timeout", ie);
    }
```

Non-primitives variables work when returning from a thread but primitives don't. Why ?

Comment: I don't see any primitives involved here. In the first version you're setting an array element in an anonymous inner class (you're allowed to do that). In the second version you're changing the value of a final variable in an anonymous inner class (you're not allowed to do that).

Comment: You can't reinitialize `final` variables, the first example works because you're using an array, you're initializing an element inside that `final` array not the object itself.

Comment: @JonSkeet The second version has newTask as a final variable.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that was a typo - I meant `final` when I said non-final. I've fixed the comment. There's still no difference in terms of primitives...

Comment: The first variant may compile, still, it is broken as the validity of what the first threads will see in `newTask[0]` is not guaranteed. Writing thread safe code is more than just getting the code to pass the compiler.

Comment: @Holger Yes, that was going to be my next question on SO. A separate question would be better right ?

Comment: Edited main question to use primitives.

Comment: By the way, you don't _'return from a thread'_.  Returning is when a value is put on the stack for the calling function to retrieve off the stack. Threads, by definition, are a (separate) (call) stack and so can't "return". You can only mutate heap memory for other threads to read it.

Comment: @dsh Totally agree. According to you, what would be an appropriate question title ?

Comment: @Viraj maybe something about assignment to final variables is not allowed (which is by definition) or something about object mutability?  It's hard to think of something clear and concise that encompasses all all that you ask here.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, `newTask` is a reference to an array. The reference cannot be changed, because it is `final`. The content of the array can be modified, because the array is not immutable.

In the second case, `newTask` is a primitive value. It can't be changed, because it is `final`.

A simpler example of the same behavior would be something like this:

```
final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
buf.append('x'); /* Modified the mutable object; no problem. */
buf = new StringBuilder(); /* Compiler error: you can't reassign final var */
```

It has nothing to do with threads, or the differences between primitive values and reference types.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing some things up. It’s not about primitives or non-primitives. In the first variant you are accessing an object by two threads, in the second, you are attempting to *assign* a variable of the surrounding context of the inner class.

The assignment can’t work as it would create an indeterminate state, as for the surrounding code the variable may be initialized or may be uninitialized. Note that the Java language is even more restrictive here, as it doesn’t care whether you are using the inner class in a multi-threaded context or not.

Returning a value from a thread via modifying a shared object is not recommended. There are too many ways to make mistakes, that’s especially true for arrays which can’t be made thread safe at all.

If you have to deal with `Thread`s manually, you can still use the concurrency tools, which help to avoid threading mistakes:

```
Callable<Integer> task=new Callable<Integer>() {
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return someMethod();
    }
};
FutureTask<Integer> f=new FutureTask<>(task);
new Thread(f).start();
try {
    Integer i=f.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // here we have a valid result
} catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException ex) {
    // log the failure
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    f.cancel(true);
}
```

but normally, you don’t create `Thread`s manually, but use an `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService threadPool=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Callable<Integer> task=new Callable<Integer>() {
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return someMethod();
    }
};
Future<Integer> f=threadPool.submit(task);
try {
    Integer i=f.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // here we have a valid result
} catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException ex) {
    // log the failure
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    f.cancel(true);
}

threadPool.shutdown();
```

This becomes even cleaner when using Java 8:

```
ExecutorService threadPool=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Future<Integer> f=threadPool.submit(() -> someMethod());
try {
    Integer i=f.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // here we have a valid result
} catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException ex) {
    // log the failure
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    f.cancel(true);
}

threadPool.shutdown();
```

Of course, the whole point of the `ExecutorService` is that you can use it to submit multiple tasks, so you are likely to create a single `ExecutorService` on application startup and call `shutdown()` at the end of the application’s lifetime.

Comment: Great answer. Solves 2 problems at once.